# How to replace a particular text in a block of text with a values from another file?

Tags: linux

I have block of repeated text lines:

```
I love banana  
I love mango  
I love papaya  
I love guava  
I love peaches  
I love baby  
I love watermelon  
I love banana  
I love mango  
I love papaya  
I love guava  
I love peaches  
I love baby  
I love watermelon  
I love banana  
I love mango  
I love papaya  
I love guava  
I love peaches  
I love baby  
I love watermelon  
I love banana
I love mango  
I love papaya  
I love guava  
I love peaches  
I love baby  
I love watermelon  
I love banana  
I love mango  
I love papaya  
I love guava  
I love peaches  
I love baby  
I love watermelon
```

I have another file with the following text:

```
D1  
D2  
D3  
D4  
D5
```

It is required that whenever the term `baby` is encountered, it is repaced by the 
sequential terms in the second file. For instance, for first `baby`, it is replaced as:

```
I love D1
```

For second `baby`, it is replaced as `D2` and so on till end of file. Displayed below are the summary of attempts made without success (mentioned in extreme haphazard manner..aplogies for that). Can someone help me please?

```
for x in `cat test1.txt|tr -d '\r'`; do awk '{gsub(/baby/,'"$x"')}' test3.txt ; done

for x in `cat test1.txt|tr -d '\r'`; do sed -i 's/baby/$x/g' test3.txt ; done

sed "0,/baby/{s/baby/$x/}" "test3.txt"  

for x in `cat test1.txt|tr -d '\r'`; do awk 'NR==1,/baby/{sub(/baby/,'"$x"')} print' test3.txt ; done  
awk '/^baby$/&&getline<"test1.txt"||1' test3.txt

awk 'NR==FNR{Arr[NR]=$0;next}{if($0==baby){i++;print Arr[i]}else{print}}' test3.txt test1.txt

#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do  
    if [[ "$line"  == baby ]]; then  
        sed -n '1p' test3.txt  
        sed -i".bup" '1d' test3.txt   
    else  
        echo "$line"  
    fi    
done < test1.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible that you'll run out of `D`s before you run out of babies?

Comment: No..it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that the number of lines in `file2.txt` is more than the number of times `baby` appear, then a simple script may be used:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ sf="file2.txt"}
     /baby/ {  getline var <sf; gsub(/baby/,var,$0) }
print
' file1.txt
```

But a much more robust script that both check if reading `file2.txt` got any error or rewinding to the start if the script reach the end of  file2.txt:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ sf="file2.txt"}
/baby/{
         # If at the end of second file, rewind to start.
         while( (test=(getline var <sf)) != 1 ){
            if( test==-1 ){ print "Error: file ",sf,":",ERRNO; exit 1 }
            if( test==0  ){ close(sf); continue }
                # This script should never get up to here
                print "Unexpected error"; exit 2
            }
         sub(/baby/,var ,$0)
     }
1
' file1.txt
```

If file2.txt contains only four D1,D2,D3,D4 lines, you will get:

```
$ ./script
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D1
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D2
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D3
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D4
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D1
I love watermelon
```

Comment: Actually, the script no doubt should be fine. However, owing to the sensitive data with me, I cannot post the actual data. This script given does not work with the data available with me. The $3 value is taken from space available in the sentence. Is it possible to modify the script based on the following text instead of "baby": >baby<

Comment: @crusader I am not sure I follow. Do you mean that you want to replace `>baby<` in file 1 by something like `>D1<` while file2 contains D1? Or that the word to match should be `>baby<` instead of `I love baby`? Both are possible, which one do you want?, or just both?

Comment: I want both. Whenever the term: >baby< is encountered, it should be replaced by items from file 2 : like >D1< and then during next encounter >D2<

Comment: @crusader Please read updated answer.

Comment: It does not work because as I mentioned earlier $3 value (implies " ") does not exist. There is no space in the entire block of actual text available with me(which cannot be shared owing to ramifications). Can a script be made which exclusively uses >baby< as the searching criteria and replaces it with D1 as mentioned earlier

Comment: Are the `>` and `<` around 'baby" the only ones in the line? That is: could them be used as delimiters? Ahhh, never mind, I believe I found  a general solution.

Comment: @crusader Answer edited, please review.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. Thanks again. You are a genius..there is no doubt about it.

Comment: @crusader Please consider accepting this answer[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

```
awk -v f='file2' '$3=="baby"{getline $3 <f}1' file1
```

Each time field3 = baby in file1 replace $3 by a line of file2.

**Edit:**

If I understand well, your line in file1 look like :

```
Ilovepeaches
Ilovemybeautifulbabygirl
Ilovewatermelon
```

And you want to replace each baby by a line from file2

So, you can try this way:

```
awk -v search='baby' -v f='file2' '
  $0 ~ search {
     split($0,lign,search)
     getline <f
     $0=lign[1]$0lign[2]
}1' file1
```

**output:**

```
Ilovepeaches
IlovemybeautifulD3girl
Ilovewatermelon
```

Comment: Actually, the script no doubt should be fine. However, owing to the sensitive data with me, I cannot post the actual data. This script given does not work with the data available with me. The $3 value is taken from space available in the sentence. Is it possible to modify the script based on the following text instead of "baby": >baby<

Answer (score 0):

With awk, `file2` containing the replacement text and `file1` the repeated text:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {baby[NR] = $0; next} /baby/ {count++; $NF = baby[count]} 1'  file2 file1
```

Note that the `file2` is the first file argument here, not `file1`.

Explanation:

- `FNR == NR` is true for the first file read by awk, so `file2` here. For that file, we save each line in an array, indexed by line number
- For the second file, we keep a `count` of each line matching `baby`, and 
  get the entry from the array for that count and replace the last field with that entry.

I get output like:

```
~ awk 'FNR == NR {baby[NR] = $0; next} /baby/ {count++; $NF = baby[count]} 1'  file2 file1
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D1
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D2
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D3
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D4
I love watermelon
I love banana
I love mango
I love papaya
I love guava
I love peaches
I love D5
I love watermelon
```

Comment: Actually, the script no doubt should be fine. However, owing to the sensitive data with me, I cannot post the actual data. This script given does not work with the data available with me. The $3 value is taken from space available in the sentence. Is it possible to modify the script based on the following text instead of "baby": >baby<

Comment: @crusader in that case, post something in the actual format and replace sensitive text with random text

Comment: <iceland Europe="loveutoo" kill:bill="http://www.googleboy.cam/5123/hit-it" love:for="twelve:love">baby</India>  
Please do note that the term >baby< needs to be replaced with the sequential contents of the next file: like D1 and then D2. This line is the one where the substitution is supposed to take place and it belongs to a block of text where it is repeated over a few number of times.

Comment: @crusader in the question, please, with code formatting